# Use .dll to store other .dlls or .libs

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and I'm trying to create a .dll. My .dll uses an external library .lib. This Library also contains a collection of other libraries (.lib).

So: My main.lib is a container for the collection of libs - and as a result it is about 300mb big.

Now when I use the lib in my dll, its linking fine and it works correctly on my pc. But when I deploy my compiled program to another computer, then it couldn't load the .lib. It simply can't find it, even when I've put it into the directory of the .dll.

Now my question: Is there a way I can store all functionality of my .lib in a .dll? So that the .dll file will be about 300mb big but I don't need to deploy the .lib anymore?

**Update:**

Thank you all very much for your answers. To descripe my problem I want to show you this output of my program:

> *Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External componennt has thrown an exception.*

I've spent many hours of using google to solve this error. I've found out that it's a problem with a missing file (one of my "external components" (.dll)) couldn't find definitions of classes and so on or otherwise a problem with access rights.

I tried my best to fix this and with one try I had success and could use this program. I know that this is because I have put the main.lib into the right folder, so my program could find it. But now I don't know where to put this main.lib. So: my program is broken again and now I want to fix it... I hope this description helps. It's hard to describe it because I don't know exactly what the problem is...

**Update 2:**

Thanks to your help I solved my problem. At first I misunderstood the principle of how .dll's and .lib's are working. If anyone else has this problem and will be redirected to this post then @D Stanley's answer will help.

Thanks to @David Heffernan I've found out that it's not any missing .lib or something else which is causing this error. It's a problem in my native C++ Code (which is in the .lib). So I fixed this problem (which caused an exception) and now everything is working fine.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: You are diagnosing the problem incorrectly. Instead of asking about your proposed solution, we first need to correctly identify the problem. At runtime, there is no use of .lib files. So the absence of the .lib file on the machine running the program is not the problem. You need to back up and provide more details of the problem.

Comment: Hello David, thank you very much for your answer! I've added an update at my previous question. Does this update help to understand my problem?

Comment: As I said, you've misdiagnosed the problem. All the talk of lib files is just unrelated to the problem. I don't think this question can be saved. You need help with the error. Ask a new question about that. With details. Plenty of details.

Comment: But I think this error relates to my problem. It shows me, that it got an error when my program tries to access the code of my main.lib. So I think it couldn't find the definition/declaration of this part. And it's in the .lib (and the given .h file). When I ask a new question about that error. What details should I give? I don't know which details I should provide. I think I can't provide even more... :/

Comment: No, it's nothing to do with any .lib files. But you don't seem to want to listen to my advice, so I guess that means I cannot help you. Good luck with solving this. I'm sorry that I cannot help you.

Comment: Hello David, you are right. It's nothing to do with the .lib files. There was an error in my the native Code. I'm sorry for not listening to your advice - I solved the SEHException and it solved the problem. Thank you very much for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can not statically link static libraries in other static libraries. What you should be doing instead is statically linking all those individual static libraries in your DLL. Does the linker not warn you about this?

Also, you can't deploy static libraries to another machine, as they can't be linked at run time.

Comment: Hello aevitas, thank you so much for your answer. Why should I not be able to link static libs in other static libs? I'm trying to create one "container" lib that holds all other smaller libs. Because: In my dll I only want to reference one lib. So I thought: when I have to take care that all small .libs are in the right directory (on my target computer, not my development computer) this will be really hard. But when I only have to take care that one .lib (the main.lib ~ container of all smaller .libs) it would be easier. But now I see... it's not that easy at all.

Comment: @user3816457 You should not be distributing those .lib files at all as machines you deploy your software to won't be able to use them. The sole purpose of a static library is to be linked to a DLL to exe file at compile time, as a static resource. As opposed to DLLs, LIB files can *not* be linked to at runtime, and are effectively useless at any other point than compile time.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm sorry that I misunderstood the principle of .dlls and .libs. I thought .dlls are trying to link the .libs at runtime. Your post helped me to solve my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your situation:

1. You have several static libraries (`.lib`)
2. They are linked together into one big static library (`main.lib`)
3. You want to use this library in your dynamic library (`.dll`)

I'm not certain what's happening locally, but `lib` files are *not* "loaded" at run-time - they are linked into either a dynamic library that *is* loaded at run time (hence the name "dynamic" or into the executable itself.  So if your application is working now, then either you're *already* linking part of it into your dll or it's getting linked into the executable.

So to answer your question, yes, you can link your `lib` file into your `dll` - and it will include all of the necessary object code into it.  Note that it may not be as big as the source library - that depends on how much of the original code is used by your library.

I also don't see how c# is part of your situation.

Comment: Hello, D Stanley. Thank you very much for your answer. Yes, you understand my situation correctly! Okay now I see the point. The dll is "intelligent" enough so that only the necessary code of the main.lib will be included in the dll? So: when I've got the .dll then I don't need the main.lib anymore? I need it only for linking purposes, right?

I've updated my main post and posted the error my program shows me. Could this relate to your answer? 

To clear the C# part: I need to use native C++ code in a C# (ASP.NET) application. So the .lib's own C++ Code, the main.lib is a C++ Wrapper around...

Comment: ... this .lib's. And in my .DLL I've got C++/CLI Code to access the C++ Wrapper. Then I want to use it in my C# Application.

I hope this explaination helps.

Comment: Correct, you do not need to deploy the lib files - the _linker_ pulls the code from the lib into the DLL.  I'd do more research on the `SEHException` and focus on that - the lib files are a red herring.

Comment: Hell D Stanley, thank you very much for your help. Your Post opened my eyes. I misunderstood the principle of .dll's and .lib's. But thanks to your post I will not make this mistake again! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

From your description it seems that you are linking with *.lib stubs that accompany DLLs for their static loading. You have those DLLs on your computer but not on other computers where you try to use your DLL. So to make everything work, find and copy those DLLs together with your DLL.

Comment: Hello Eugene, thank you for your answer. I'm using these DLLs to link native C++ libraries to my C# Software. But I've put all necessary DLLs on the new computer.